# Use of undeclared identifier 'kUTTypeMovie'

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mobilecoreservices

I am getting the error message - **Use of undeclared identifier 'kUTTypeMovie'**

in the below code -

```
-(IBAction)selectVideo:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];

    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
}
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 315, accepted):

You have to add the framework MobileCoreServices to the project, and then import it:

**Objective C:**

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
```

That will make the problem go away.

**Swift 4:**

```
import MobileCoreServices
```

Comment: `@import MobileCoreServices;` - for Objective-C

Answer (score 38):

**swift**

```
import MobileCoreServices
```

**objective c**

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
```

Answer (score 20):

I am a novice at iOS development and xcode and spent some time trying to find out why just the import was not working. After figuring out the problem with a more experienced member of my team I found out that not only must you include

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
```

but you must also link binaries to the library of the MobileCoreServices framework to the build phases of your project.

Hope this helps! I sure needed this info when I was doing this.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4** answer, with video camera code and imagePicker delegate:

```
import MobileCoreServices
```

**Open Video Camera**

```
   @IBAction func openVideoCamera(_ sender: Any) {
     if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
        imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 10 // or whatever you want
        imagePicker.videoQuality = .typeMedium
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

**ImagePicker delegate:**

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as AnyObject

    if mediaType as! String == kUTTypeMovie as String {
            let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL
            print("VIDEO URL: \(videoURL!)")
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`import MobileCoreServices` for swift 
`@import MobileCoreServices;` for objective c

Answer (score 1):

1. Add MobileCoreServices.framework if not added already. Select your target and add linked binaries with library.
2. Add `#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>`